# How to create dynamic hyperlinks based on a drop down selection in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink

I am trying to create a contents sheet for an Excel I have. The Excel has three tabs called: On-grid, Off-grid, Embedded.

Each tab is divided into regions: Africa, North Africa, South Africa, East Africa, West Africa, Central Africa. They are not in the same position in each tab.

Each region has three headings: Capacity, Total, Installed. Again they are not in the same position in each tab.

I want to have two drop downs in the contents sheet, one for the tab name and one for the region. The contents list will be a list of the three headings. So a user can select 'On-grid' and 'North Africa' from the drop downs, then click on the 'Capacity' hyperlink. Which will take them to the 'On-grid' tab and to the Capacity heading under North Africa.

This is what I so far:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX('On-grid'!B:B,MATCH(config!B2,'On-grid'!B:B,0))),config!B2)
```

This just creates a hyperlink based on a heading value contained in the 'config' tab and will navigate to the first occurrence of that heading in the 'On-grid' tab. I can't figure out how to create a hyperlink based on drop down selections.

Comment: take a look at the indirect function

Comment: @ForwardEd ah thank you, that's what I was trying to figure out. Indirect was the right function to use.